Problem with inductive definition of a set.
From what I understand, inductive definition of a set includes 2 clauses. A basis clause stating that certain elements are in the set, and an inductive clause which states that if x is in the set, y is also in the set.
Now the problem that I have with this definition is that for many objects, it does not specify if they are in the set or not (which are not taken into account in both of the clauses). For example in the question attached, I cannot tell if b belongs to L or not. A good definition of a set should be able to define for every object in the universe of discourse, that it belongs to the set or not. The answer here, also completely depends on this assumption. My question is, am I missing something in the way sets are defined inductively, or the question is just vague and poorly framed, or the inductive definition of sets is incomplete and there are better ways to define a set?
I'm happy to provide any clarifications in my post. TY.

The attached image describes of a property of a set $L$. There can be many such sets $L$ with that property, and you are given one of them. In such a case you may or may not be able to prove that $b \in L$.

The question is poorly phrased. They clearly want to be talking about the least such set $L$ (i.e. the one inductively defined by those properties), but do not say so explicitly.

You have equally valid reason to believe $b \in L$ as you do to believe $\text{Puff the magic dragon} \in L$.  The definition never specifically states $b \not \in L$ but it never states $\text{Puff the magic dragon}\not \in L$ either.  I think they claim this is a "definition" implies they are claiming $L$ only contains elements that can be inductively shown to be in $L$ (i.e. the least such set). As Naim Favier points out it never explicitly claimed so.  But I think it implicitly claimed so and the word "definition" makes no sense unless it is implied. IMO it is not poorly phrased.

BTW it is poor form to post images.  You should, if it is at all possible, include the information as text in the body of your question.

It is poorly phrased. Without clarification, it could just as well be a coinductive definition, for example.

I'm not sure whether a "good definition" needs to satisfy your requirement. For instance $$
Q = \{n \in \mathbb Z \mid H(n) \wedge \nexists k: ((k > n) \wedge H(k)) \},
$$ where $H(n)$ is the assertion that "both $n$ and $n+2$ are prime" is a well-defined set, but no one knows whether $Q$ is empty. And at any moment, the largest known twin-prime pair provides a number $n$ for which we do not know whether $n$ is in $Q$.
Inductive definitions are easy to write sloppily. A classic example is something like
1. empty is a list
2. if s is a list and u is an item, then (cons u s) is a list

as a means of defining lists. What's missing is
3. nothing else is a list

There are similar informal descriptions of natural numbers (start with 0; adding 1 to a natural always gives a natural. But they seldom say "and nothing else is a natural.")
Even when you do include rule 3, if you give a bunch of recursive ways of constructing a new item in a set (i.e., if there are rules 2a, 2b, 2c, ..., 2q, say!), then to test rule 3 on some new item $z$, you have to ask whether every possible sequence of prior rule applications fails to produce $z$. That sounds like an infinite amount of testing!
If (as in the rule for lists), there's some quantity that increases with every rule application, then you can look at z and say "for z, that quantity is 13, so I need only consider all possible applications of no more than 13 rules", and then that's a finite problem. [For lists, that quantity is 'length', i.e., the number of times 'cons' appears after a left-paren.] If you can't find such a quantity, or some other clever proof method, then the definition really is inadequate.
I suspect that there's a general agreement among people who do this stuff all the time that rule 3 is implicit (after all, it's always going to say "nothing else is in my set"), but I certainly share your frustration, especially if this is the first time you're seeing inductive definitions.
